# MS-Excel VB Macro - Filter and Transfer

Tags: vba, excel

Im learning Microsoft Excel as my subject, I have given a task to make a filter using VBA Macro.

> This is what I have:
>
> > Worksheet("Main") ,
> >     Worksheet("USA") , 
> >      Worksheet("Asia") and  Worksheet("Europe")

This is what I have to do:

> Pasting some data from user clipboard to Worksheet("Main"). Count all the data with the same continents and get the 10% of total inputs  (i.e: a total of 1000 input pasted on Worksheet main, 500 from Africa,350 from Asia, and 150 from Europe. so the data that will copy from worksheet("Africa") is 50 inputs only, those 50 inputs should have filter from the AMOUNT column

Here's my header from all Worksheets,

LOCAL | AMOUNT | CONTINENT | Additional Comments |

---

Now here's what I made while surfing the net.

```
    Sub copyPasteData()
        Dim strSourceSheet As String
        Dim strDestinationSheet As String
        Dim lastRow As Long
        strSourceSheet = "Main"
        Sheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
        Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
        Range("C2").Select ' This is where I could filter the CONTINENTS.
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Visible = True
        Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
        lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A")
       Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Function LastRowInOneColumn(col)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        LastRowInOneColumn = lastRow
    End Function
```

With the code above, I can filter based on the continent given. But the problem is how can I get the 10% of the total input that the user paste?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sort by continent.

Once the information is sorted, you can count the items for each continent so you know how many inputs "should have a filter from the AMOUNT column."